# Как отключить передвижение заголовков Pivot'а?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Пытаюсь создать Pivot табами. Вроде бы как все закончил, но из за того что элементы примыкают к краям приложения они начинают "бегать". Т.е. появляются стрелочки для смены страниц и сами Header'ы меняются местами, что мне конечно же очень мешает. Как отключить эту анимацию/особенность Pivot'а?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разметку покажите. Как написано [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tabs-pivot) когда все заголовки не помещаются на экране - они переходят в режим карусели. Вы это имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Андрей Именно. разметка самая обычная не вижу смысла ее приводить. Просто я думаю что есть какой-либо параметр Pivot'а либо строка в правке шаблона, которые могут это исправить

Comment: Вряд ли, уменьшайте длину заголовков и ограничивайте минимальную ширину окна приложения (на мобильном не прокатит). Другой вариант - написать свой контроль со сходным функционалом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

недавно делал тоже самое под UWP. Только я ещё свайпабельными табы сделал

```
<Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem"
       x:Key="TabControlPivotHeaderTemplate">
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" /> 
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
    <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing"
            Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1 1 1 0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid"
                      Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                      MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"
                      Margin="4 4 4 0"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="Unselected"
                                                  To="UnselectedLocked"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                                <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked"
                                                  To="Unselected"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform.X"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Opacity"
                                            Value="0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Grid.Background"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SelectedTabBackground}" /> 
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Grid.Background"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Grid.Background"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SelectedTabBackground}" /> 
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Grid.Background"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Grid.Background"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource SelectedTabBackground}" /> 
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                      FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                      FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                        </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Style TargetType="controls:TabControl">
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="IsHeaderItemsCarouselEnabled"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:TabControl">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HeaderStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderDynamic" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="HeaderStatic">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Header.Visibility"
                                            Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="StaticHeader.Visibility"
                                            Value="Visible" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
                                      HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                      VerticalSnapPointsType="None"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                      ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                      Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}"
                                      BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False">
                            <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="PivotLayoutElementTranslateTransform" />
                                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                                  VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                                    BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
                                                    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationBorderBrush}">

                                            <StackPanel.Resources>
                                                <Style TargetType="Button"
                                                       x:Key="AddButtonStyle">
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                                            Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationBorderBrush}" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Background"
                                                            Value="White" />
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                                            Value="1 1 1 0" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Padding"
                                                            Value="8,4,8,4" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                                                            Value="4 4 0 0" /> 
                                                    <Setter Property="Height"
                                                            Value="28" /> 
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
                                                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                                      CornerRadius="3 3 0 0"
                                                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                                    <Setter Target="FontIcon.Foreground"
                                                                                            Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonPointerOverForegroundBorderBrush}" />
                                                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                                                    <Setter Target="FontIcon.Foreground"
                                                                                            Value="{ThemeResource AccentButtonPointerOverForegroundBorderBrush}" />
                                                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                                                            </VisualState>
                                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                                    <FontIcon x:Name="FontIcon"
                                                                              FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                                                              FontSize="12"
                                                                              Glyph="&#xE109;" />
                                                                </Grid>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Style>

                                            </StackPanel.Resources>

                                            <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderClipper"
                                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                                            UseSystemFocusVisuals="True"
                                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                                <ContentControl.Clip>
                                                    <RectangleGeometry x:Name="HeaderClipperGeometry" />
                                                </ContentControl.Clip>

                                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                                    <Grid.Resources>
                                                        <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem"
                                                               BasedOn="{StaticResource TabControlPivotHeaderTemplate}">
                                                            <Setter Property="Height"
                                                                    Value="32" />
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </Grid.Resources>

                                                    <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="StaticHeader"
                                                                      Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                                    <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
                                                        <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" />
                                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderOffsetTranslateTransform" />
                                                            </TransformGroup>
                                                        </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                    </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                                </Grid>

                                            </ContentControl>

                                            <Button Command="{Binding CreateTabCommand}" 
                                                    Style="{StaticResource AddButtonStyle}" />

                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter"
                                                    Grid.Row="1">
                                        <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterCompositeTransform" />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    </ItemsPresenter>
                                </Grid>
                            </PivotPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Сам табконтрол

```
  public sealed class TabControl : Pivot
{
    public TabControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TabControl);
    }


    #region DependencyProperty
    public ICommand CreateTabCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CreateTabCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CreateTabCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CreateTabCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CreateTabCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(TabControl), new PropertyMetadata(null)); 
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: там даже можно  ещё немного вырезать кода

Answer (score 0):

Из стиля пивота надо выпилить всё, что связано с Dynamic Header, кнопками и т.п.